# Basic Feasible Solution

Tags: julia, linear-programming

I am trying to create a function in Julia that tests whether a basis matrix of a matrix A is a basic feasible solution. For some reason that I cannot figure out, whenever I run my code, no matter the inputs I put in for my function, I get the same output. Here is my code:

```
function is_bfs(A, b, basic_col_indices)
    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)

    # check if input is a standard form polyhedron
    if m > n || length(b) != m || rank(A) != m
        @warn("Input is not a standard form polyhedron!")
        return false
    end
    
    # remove duplicate entries
     unique!(sort!(basic_col_indices))
    
    # check if input data is consistent
    if !issubset(basic_col_indices, 1:n) || length(basic_col_indices) != m
        @warn("basic_col_indices is not a subset of [1,...,n] of cardinality m")
        return false
    end
    
    for basic_col_indices in combinations(1:n, m)
         B = A[:, basic_col_indices]
         x_B = inv(B) * b
    end
    
    if det(B) == 0
        return false
    end
    
    if any(x_B .< -1e-12)
        value = false
    else 
         value= true
    end
    println(value)
    println(B)
    println(x_B)
    return value
end
```

Comment: Sorry I do not know why it formatted this why, but the line above the markdown is a part of my code. As well as the end afterwards.

Comment: The reason the code wasn't formatted is you didn't surround your code block with code fences (```).  It looks like another user has since fixed that for you.

Comment: And what is "the same output" ?

Comment: The loop is iterating over all combinations of `m` columns from `1:n` but it doesn't use the input `basic_col_indices` that you passed to the function. Instead, it overwrites `basic_col_indices` with each iteration.

Comment: true
[1.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0]
[3.0; 3.0;;] This is the output i keep getting @AndyRay

Comment: ok so should I get rid of the loop and try to define my basis matrix some way else? @AboAmmar

Comment: A = [ 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.0;
     2.0 1.0 0.0 1.0]
b = [3.0 3.0]'
is_bfs(A, b, [1, 2]) Here is the input I was using to test my function

Comment: @AboAmmar I removed the loop and the code worked properly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The loop is iterating over all combinations of `m` columns from `1:n` but it doesn't use the input `basic_col_indices` that you passed to the function. Instead, it overwrites `basic_col_indices` with each iteration. I also used `B \ b` which is sometimes better than `inv(B) * b` and `if any(<(-1e-12), x_B)` doesn't allocate a new array as `if any(x_B .< -1e-12)` does.

```
function is_bfs(A, b, basic_col_indices)
    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)

    # check if input is a standard form polyhedron
    if m > n || length(b) != m || rank(A) != m
        @warn("Input is not a standard form polyhedron!")
        return false
    end
    
    # remove duplicate entries
    unique!(sort!(basic_col_indices))
    
    # check if input data is consistent
    if !issubset(basic_col_indices, 1:n) || length(basic_col_indices) != m
        @warn("basic_col_indices is not a subset of [1,...,n] of cardinality m")
        return false
    end
    
    B = A[:, basic_col_indices]
    det(B) == 0 && return false
    
    x_B = B \ b
    value = all(>(-1e-12), x_B)
    
    println(value)
    println(B)
    println(x_B)
    
    return value
end
```